# Suppress "Running SSH command" from remote execution

Tags: ssh, ignore

When I attempt to run a command in a remote server, for instance :

```
ssh user@server 'app; exit \$?'
```

I get an annoying output from ssh stating :

```
Running SSH command :
....
```

And the exact command is going to be run on the remote server.  I don't want that output. I'm only interested in the exit code from my app, which I'm getting correctly. How can I suppress this?

Answer (score 1):

Find out where it's coming from.

Check your local shell aliases, your local ssh config on your local system, and also check the shell startup scripts on the remote system.

Comment: You are saying this is not coming from ssh binary on my Mac? That it might be coming from somewhere else?

Comment: ssh doesn't print annoying stuff like that, unless you tell it to with verbosity (e.g. `-v`).